# SMTP protocol synchronization error in Exim4 when connecting from Gmail

Tags: debian, gmail, smtp, tls, exim

I have a Exim 4.92 server running on a Debian machine, everything works fine. Now I want to send mails from Gmail through that Exim server, since Gmail needs an STMP server for alias addresses.

However, when I try to send a mail from Gmail via my server using SSL, I get the following error in Exim's `mainlog` file:

```
SMTP protocol synchronization error (input sent without waiting for greeting): rejected connection from H=mail-ot1-f48.google.com [209.85.210.48] input="\026\003\001\002"
```

I am not an Exim expert, and I don't have messed around with its configuration file so far. I am using the default settings I get from Debian's Exim configuration tool.

To enable TLS support in Exim I followed [this Debian documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/Exim#TLS_and_authentication). Thus I basically generated the certificate files and enabled TLS in the `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.localmacros` file via

```
MAIN_TLS_ENABLE = yes
```

Here is my `/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf` file:

```
dc_eximconfig_configtype='internet'
dc_other_hostnames='...'   # my list of allowed domains
dc_local_interfaces=''
dc_readhost=''
dc_relay_domains=''
dc_minimaldns='false'
dc_relay_nets=''
dc_smarthost=''
CFILEMODE='644'
dc_use_split_config='false'
dc_hide_mailname=''
dc_mailname_in_oh='true'
dc_localdelivery='maildir_home'
```

Any ideas how I can solve this error?

Comment: Sounds like your Exim isn't configured to use implicit (SSL/TLS) and explicit (STARTTLS) ports correctly. (`\026\003\001` is the start of a TLS 1.0 handshake.) I use Exim on Debian too and get this, but haven't found an answer yet sorry. -- This may be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29091778/smtp-protocol-synchronization-error-input-sent-without-waiting-for-greeting